# Get from WinDBG a full stack trace (user stack + kernel strack)

Tags: debugging, stack, windbg

I have set a breakpoint in nt!ntWriteFile from Windbg. I'm using kernel debugging and I want to get the user stack + kernel stack trace when certain program (for example, notepad.exe) ends up calling this API.  When the breakpoint kicks in I do the following:

```
.reload /user
K
```

but the result is similar to this (in this case notepad.exe is the current process):

```
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 8f5a8c34 76e96c73 nt!NtWriteFile
01 8f5a8c38 badb0d00 ntdll!KiFastSystemCall+0x3
02 8f5a8c3c 0320ef04 0xbadb0d00
03 8f5a8c40 00000000 0x320ef04
```

My question are:

1. What is 0xbadb0d00? I always see this address.
2. Is the address 0x320ef04 the function on user land (inside notepad.exe in this case) from which the call begins? In this case, would that be the full stack trace (user stack + kernel stack).
3. Is there another easier way to get this?

Thank you.

**Updated:**
As I read in this [link](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=236336) (thanks to Thomas Weller) 0xbadb0d00 is used to initialize uninitialized memory in some circumstances. Now I have even more doubts. Why does the stack trace show uninitialized memory? Why notepad.exe stack-trace does not appear in the output if I'm in its context?

The Windows host I'm debugging is a Windows 7 32 bits.

Comment: I'm debugging a Windows 7 32 bits. The symbol path is correct.

Comment: Did you enable the ksl ("Enable loading of kernel debugger symbols") GlobalFlag?